# Vue2 Date-Picker Date Time Format Empty Problem

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datetime, datepicker

I'm using vue2-datepicker to represent starting and ending time of meeting in a company. In our backend we store the dates in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" format but when we get the data, we convert it on the mounted() hook in "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm" because in our country this is the correct way to represent the date.

I'm using the same method for all the datepickers but this one bothers me with HH:mm.
When the data comes from API, I use a function called "`responseDateTimeFormatter`" which slices the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm` formatted date and converts into the one I mentioned earlier.
When I post the data, I also use `requestDateTimeFormatter` to convert it again as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm` to be stored on database.

Here is the problem, after I convert the data into the format that I want, the `<date-picker>s` are all empty. Even though their format attribute is set to same one with my date's.

Here are my codes:

DatePicker:

```
              <date-picker ref="startDatepicker" id="startDate" name="startDate" v-model="meeting.startDate" :first-day-of-week="1" type="datetime" format="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm" @change="startDateClick" :disabled-date="disableStartDate" :time-picker-options="timePickerOptions"></date-picker>
```

After I convert the data the v-model looks as follows

```
meetingStartDate = 30-07-2022 09:30
```

As I explained earlier, it is in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm` format when it came from response.
I convert it with responseFormatter function below;

```
  responseTimeFormatter(dateTime) {
    var day = dateTime.slice(8, 10);
    var month = dateTime.slice(5, 7);
    var year = dateTime.slice(0, 4);
    var time = dateTime.slice(11, 16);

    return day + "-" + month + "-" + year + " " + time;
  },
```

Here is my `then()` block;

```
  .then((response) => {
    this.meeting = response
    console.log("MEETING", this.meeting)
    this.meeting.startDate = this.responseTimeFormatter(response.startDate)
    console.log("Start Date", this.meeting.startDate)
    
    this.meeting.endDate = this.responseTimeFormatter(response.endDate)
    console.log("End Date", this.meeting.endDate)
  })
```

So after all these, meeting.startDate is in the right format. The v-model of the DatePicker above is in the right format (same with the format attribute of the date picker) but still I am not seeing the date in my date-picker. It is empty. [image]

There is no problem when I use it without HH:mm but in datetime format it gives me this problem. Is there anyone have experienced this problem? What is the solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I checked out the `vue2-datepicker` package and when I pass string date as input it shows me an empty field so I think it does not accept string type as a date you must pass a date object

actually, you don't need that `responseTimeFormatter` function pass your DateTime string to the Date object, and done :)

modify your `then` block like this:

```js
 .then((response) => {
    this.meeting = response
 
    this.meeting.startDate = new Date(response.startDate)
    this.meeting.endDate = new Date(response.endDate)
  })
```

#### To convert that long string that comes from the Date object to your backend format, you can use this way

define these two functions in your `methods` object:

```js
  methods: {
    padTo2Digits(num) {
      return num.toString().padStart(2, "0");
    },
    formatDate(date) {
      return (
        [
          date.getFullYear(),
          this.padTo2Digits(date.getMonth() + 1),
          this.padTo2Digits(date.getDate()),
        ].join("-") +
        " " +
        [
          this.padTo2Digits(date.getHours()),
          this.padTo2Digits(date.getMinutes()),
          this.padTo2Digits(date.getSeconds()),
        ].join(":")
      );
    },
  },
```

and when you call your API to send data to your backend use this:

```js
// some code here for API call
this.formatDate(this.meeting.startDate)
```

**References**:

[Format a Date as YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss in JavaScript](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-format-date-yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss)

[Date Object JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)